# How to access a full array retrived from firebase database in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

```
REACT NATIVE CODE
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        day: '',
        month: '',
        year: '',
        asked_dat: '',
        asked_clas: 'CLASS',
        asked_su: 'SUBJECT'
    };
}

set_date = () => {
    this.setState({
        asked_dat: this.state.day + '-' + this.state.month + '-' + this.state.year
    });
};
retrieve_data = () => {
    var asked_date = this.state.asked_dat;
    var asked_class = this.state.asked_clas + '/';
    var asked_sub = this.state.asked_su;
    var date_class = asked_date + '/' + asked_class;
    var sub_roll = asked_sub + '/' + 'PRESENT_ROLL_NO';

    console.log(date_class + sub_roll);
    db.ref(date_class).once('value', function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.child(sub_roll).val());
    });
};
```

when i assign an array variable like
temp_arr = snapshot.child(sub_roll).val();
it returns empty array but if console log it i get the array,
please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are assigning an array variable to the result outside the `value` event then it will return empty since `once()` is asynchronous which means it will not wait until the data is retrieved, therefore if you do this:

```
    db.ref(date_class).once('value', function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.child(sub_roll).val());
    });
     temp_arr = snapshot.child(sub_roll).val();
};
```

`temp_arr` will return an empty array. You need to do the following:

```
    db.ref(date_class).once('value', function(snapshot) {
        temp_arr = snapshot.child(sub_roll).val();
        console.log(temp_arr);
    });
};
```

To access it outside the `value` event do the following:

```
retrieve_data = () => {
 return  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var asked_date = this.state.asked_dat;
    var asked_class = this.state.asked_clas + '/';
    var asked_sub = this.state.asked_su;
    var date_class = asked_date + '/' + asked_class;
    var sub_roll = asked_sub + '/' + 'PRESENT_ROLL_NO';

    console.log(date_class + sub_roll);
    db.ref(date_class).once('value', function(snapshot) {
        temp_arr = snapshot.child(sub_roll).val();
        resolve(temp_arr);
    });
  });
};
```

Then when calling the function do the following:

```
retrieve_data().then((value) => {
  console.log(value); //returns array
});
```

Comment: hey peter thanks for such fast response. but i want to use the array that i got from fiebase throughout my program outside the value event so how can i do that??